# Check whether or not a user is suspended or not on Twitter?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I have a series of accounts and I needed to check whether or not they're suspended.

I've tried 'users/lookup' - which is supposed to not have a returned value if they're suspended, however with my account that I have that I know for a fact is suspended it returns a value. Which is an issue.

Could anyone assist me? Thanks.

```
$get_them = $connection[$x]->get('users/lookup', array('screen_name' => $name[$x]));
```

I have an array of connections (as depicted above) - then the code above is executed ($x is a integer 1-24), the suspended twitter account [here](http://twitter.com/Czn_), is executed to show only the user/lookup code [here](http://sweetleaks.com/usrtest.php).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because Twitter changed some stuff in their API. After some research I found that command "users/show" can be used now to check if account is suspended. Run this command instead of users/lookup and look for "suspended" variable. If its value is 1, the account is suspended.